# How to find distance traveled Tkinter ButtonPress

Tags: python, button, tkinter, drag

I can track where the user clicks and where they release but I want to track distance traveled.

from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

class DragCursor():

```
def __init__(self, location):
    self.label = location
    location.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.StartMove)
    location.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.StopMove)


def StartMove(self, event):
    startx = event.x
    starty = event.y
    print [startx, starty]

def StopMove(self, event):
    self.StartMove
    stopx = event.x
    stopy = event.y
    print [stopx, stopy]



location = Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
DragCursor(location)
location.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The indentation of your code example is messed up.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use the distance formula for determining the distance between two points in an xy-plane,

[image: Distance Formula Wikipedia]

Also, you need to include some kind of instance variable that will save the coordinates for the start and end points so that you can compute it after the mouse release.

This is pretty much your code just with a new `distancetraveled` function that is printed at the end of `StopMove` using `self.positions`.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class DragCursor():
    def __init__(self, location):
        self.label = location
        location.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.StartMove)
        location.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.StopMove)
        self.positions = {}

    def StartMove(self, event):
        startx = event.x
        starty = event.y
        self.positions['start'] = (startx, starty)

    def StopMove(self, event):
        stopx = event.x
        stopy = event.y
        self.positions['stop'] = (stopx, stopy)
        print self.distancetraveled()

    def distancetraveled(self):
        x1 = self.positions['start'][0]
        x2 = self.positions['stop'][0]
        y1 = self.positions['start'][1]
        y2 = self.positions['stop'][1]
        return ((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**0.5

location = Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
DragCursor(location)
location.pack()
root.mainloop()
```